# It it possible to make $unwind fast in MongoDB by having an index?

Tags: mongodb

Inside a collection I have objects that contain an array and I would like to look for certain objects within that array without looking at the whole array. The objects in my collection look like this:

```
{
    "transactions": [
        {"id": randint(0, 100000), "hello": randint(0, 1000)} for _ in range(100000)
    ]
}
```

And I would like to get all the transactions that have the id 17 within the collection. So I created this index:

```
db.toto.createIndex({'transactions.id': 1})
```

But to look at only the transactions I want I have to do an $unwind and this unwind is still slow:

```
db.toto.aggregate(
        [
            {"$match": {"transactions.id": 17}},
            {"$unwind": "$transactions"},
            {"$match": {"transactions.id": 17}},
        ]
    )
```

Gives me

```
    [{'_id': ObjectId('5bf854f685699a394ce5ba82'),
  'transactions': {'hello': 920, 'id': 17}},
 {'_id': ObjectId('5bf854f685699a394ce5ba82'),
  'transactions': {'hello': 446, 'id': 17}},
 {'_id': ObjectId('5bf854f685699a394ce5ba84'),
  'transactions': {'hello': 822, 'id': 17}},
 {'_id': ObjectId('5bf854f685699a394ce5ba84'),
  'transactions': {'hello': 830, 'id': 17}},
 [...]
 {'_id': ObjectId('5bf854f885699a394ce5ba89'),
  'transactions': {'hello': 301, 'id': 17}},
 {'_id': ObjectId('5bf854f985699a394ce5ba8b'),
  'transactions': {'hello': 666, 'id': 17}}]
```

Adding the first $match makes the query slightly faster because it does use the index to find only the objects that contain the transaction I am looking for. But it will not use the index to make the $unwind faster. MongoDB still goes through the whole array that contains 100000 transactions to find the transactions I want.

The query takes 5 seconds to find about 100 objects. While a query like this `db.toto.count({"transactions.id": 17})` that does use the index takes less than 0.1 second.

Here is the [python file](https://pastebin.com/7PhLKzPz) I used to study the issue. You can reproduce the issue by doing:

```
pip3 install fire pymongo
chmod +x toto_mongo.py
./toto_mongo.py insert
./toto_mongo.py create_index
time ./toto_mongo.py slow_query
```

Comment: Indexes can be used only on the first stage and only for some stages. Try if https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/ is any faster than unwind + match

Comment: I did use a filter too and it is slightly faster but it still takes more that a second to finish the query so it clearly does not use the index either. The query is in the python file.

Comment: No it doesn't and won't do in foreseeable future: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/#aggregation-pipeline-operators-and-performance  says "Only $match and $sort can benefit from indexes and only when used in first stage".  It's db side, doesn't matter which client driver/language you use.

Comment: $unwind will just iterate on all the elements in an array for each document, and will expend thrm to to different documents. Index cannot help you here, the only thong you can do is (as mentioned above) filter the results as much as possible before the unwind stage, or consider storing your data in a different format (not in arrays)..

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$lookup` and then *unwind* it using `$unwind`.

Something like this you can use in your backend routes.

```
               {
                    $lookup: {
                        from: "customers",
                        localField: "customer",
                        foreignField: "_id",
                        as: "customerData"
                    }
                },
                { $unwind: "$customerData" },
```

Where as your schema would look something like below:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId;

var moviesSchema = new Schema({
    movieId: String,
    title: String, 
    customer: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'customers', index: true },
    genre: String,
    releaseDate: Date,
    ratings: Number,
    review: String,
    reviewTime: Date,
});
var movieState = mongoose.model('movies', moviesSchema);

module.exports = movieState;
```